# Facebook app how to post on users wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-wall

I've developed an Facebook app: http://ek2012spel.startpagina.nl/. I've developed one before and the last time I've included the option to post a message on your wall whenever you scored a point.

But I noticed Facebook changed it's policy to prevent spamming to a wall. And I salute them for it. So I wanted to try something else.

- Include a Like Button.
- Only the people that press the Like button get news updates in their stream.
- The news updates won't be automated. It will be me telling them a new round has started or something similar.

I'm pretty sure this is (or at least was) possible. Question is; how?

- Should I create a seperate Facebook user for my app?
- A new page (or is it called tab)? And link the Like button on my app to that page?

Sub issue: My current Like Button is linked to an (old) URL. The URL redirects to the new one. Any chance I can change the URL without losing all the likes?

Comment: I have found this article: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Communicating_With_Users/.

It talks about the new policy and using a Facebook 'App page' to communicate with your users. Thing is I can't see how to create a page for my App. In the http://www.facebook.com/developers/ environment there is talk of pages but one of the required parameters there is an iframe URL. Very confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That document was referring to an old App Profile page - these were removed in February -I've updated that doc to show the current way to create a page for your app (the option is now in the 'Advanced' tab of the app settings.)

Based on what you've said above, you should do one of the following:

- Create a page for the app and get users to like it, and then use the page to post updates for the game's user
- Use [app to user requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#app_to_user) to alert the user that something has happened - this will increment a counter in the user's bookmark for your app to bring them back to it
- Obtain the user's email address from the API (needs the `email` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)) and email them directly.

Posting to user's timelines (/USER_ID/feed) automatically each time you have news to share will result in the spam filters shutting down your app very quickly indeed  (bear in mind this will appear to all their friends as a message 'from' that user)